# windows 7 ultimate, how can I make it so autorun happens only when I insert a specific removeable disk?

Tags: windows-7, autorun, memorystick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable AutoRun for specific external drive](https://superuser.com/questions/188311/disable-autorun-for-specific-external-drive)

I have a memory stick with my password vault on it.  More specifically, I have an 8G Micro SD HC (the tiny ones) inside a MicroSD adapter, and use my PC's memory stick slot to load it.  I want it to autorun when I insert but all other autorun relatives remain disabled.