# Disable Device Stage Capability

Tags: windows-7, autorun, regedit, autoplay

Is it possible to prevent or disable autorun/autoplay/device-stage by modifying regedit?

Because of some constraints, I cannot disable by Control Panel options.

I found some related questions here, [for example](https://superuser.com/q/188311/120929), and some solutions provided by Microsoft, mainly involving this key on regedit:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun
```

But none of these solutions worked, neither after rebooting.

Is there any other key or value that controls this kind of property?

**Edit:**

I don't have physical access to the computer, this is my two options are:

Do this through some script that modify a key/value from registry or programmatically.

**Edit 2:**

Changing the value of NoDriveTypeAutorun above to 0xFF disabled AutoPlay for media files but not for devices.

Comment: Uh, generally... if you can't do it with control panel, you AIN'T gonna be able to do it with regedit... can you even RUN regedit?  and edit/save the registry?  Lockdowns are for a reason. Not always a GOOD reason... but someone had a reason.  Try holding SHIFT when you insert your device, it'll disable auto-run for that insertion.

Comment: Precisely what kind of "AutoPlay" are you referring to? Because "Autoplay for devices" doesn't really make sense. A USB mouse doesn't have Autoplay; it has driver installation.

Comment: When a camera is plugged into usb port for example. It initiates the device stage feature (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-Device-Stage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. There is two categories:

**- [AutoPlay Turn On/Off](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/174838-autoplay-turn-off.html)**

Set

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\DisableAutoplay

to 0 to turn on and 1 to turn off.

Or

Set

> KEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun

the value with the [mask](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715) to turn off. To turn on just apply the default value (0x91 or 0x95).

**- [Nonvolume Devices](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/183209-autoplay-enable-disable-non-volume-devices.html)**

**Disable:**

Set

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoAutoplayfornonVolume

to 1

Remove value

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoAutoplayfornonVolume

**Enable:**

Remove both values

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoAutoplayfornonVolume
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoAutoplayfornonVolume

Answer (score 0):

Try holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you insert your device, it'll disable auto-run for **that** insertion.

Comment: I don't have physical access to the computer.

Comment: Well, THAT wasn't specified in the original question.  But ok...

Comment: Yeah, I know, I made wrong assumptions when I said that I had "some constraints". Sorry and thanks for helping.