# How do I scan a USB 3G modem for malware without reinfecting the PC?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, trojan, virus-removal, autoplay

My mother's Windows XP system recently got infected with the SHeur trojan (SHeur4.ese). I was able to download and install Malwarebytes Anti-Malware in line with the advice [here](http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?t=29065), but the modem was bringing up odd errors and thereafter was unable to go online. This makes things extra tricky, as I was helping from overseas via Logmein, and Malwarebytes can't update itself.

Still, Malwarebytes claims to have removed the infection, but I suspect that the [modem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcjZ1.jpg) may also be infected, and will reinfect the PC when it is plugged back in.

How do we disable Windows XP autoplay or otherwise prevent infection when she plugs it in, so that she can scan it?

Any other advice would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has instructions here on how to disable autoplay: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715

There are manual ways and then there are patches you can download from the site to do it automatically.

The modem may show up as a USB memory stick and be given a drive letter. Scan that drive letter using MBAM and your local antivirus software.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be able to download those patches, of course, but it looks like it will be possible by manually editing the registry. I'll have to talk my mother through it over the phone. In your opinion, will disabling autoplay make it safe to plug in the USB modem if it's infection?

Comment: Well, manually editing the registry had the desired result. This article also helped me (shorter than the MS one): http://superuser.com/questions/37569/disable-autoplay-of-audio-cds-and-usb-drives-with-registry (Having less luck clearing the infection though.)